# How to prevent iCloud from downloading (storing) certain files in an Xcode project in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, xcode, mac-appstore

I have enabled storing Desktop & Document Folders in iCloud. I keep my Xcode projects on Desktop. Every hour or so, iCloud will store files, inside of Pods folder present alongside the Xcode Project in iCloud. This is very tedious as I then have to click on each one of them one-by-one to re-download.

How can I prevent iCloud from downloading my files in this manner, for this specific Xcode project?

I have tried disabling iCloud for Desktop, but this results in me losing all my Desktop folders/files, so I could rather not go this route.

Comment: How much local disk space do you have and how much data in t he cloud

Comment: Access iCloud settings in System Preferences and check if you have Optimise Mac Storage enabled.

Comment: @user151019 11Gb local. 47gb in cloud

Comment: @NimeshNeema I do

Comment: @Outsider If you uncheck it, it would cause all the files to download and remain available. You'd no longer need to download files individually, but all the files would continue to be stored in iCloud too.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Do you know what to do if you have more cloud storage than local storage and don't want project files offloaded? Selecting "Remove Download" ultimately doesn't work, because iCloud just reattempts to download the files again a day or two later

Answer (score 1):

Such an option to force iCloud to keep some files would be nice. In the meantime, you can check OneDrive. It fits this purpose. You can decide if some files/ folders have to be kept offline.

A way is to use aliases. Then again, you'd have to check if Xcode can work with that.

- Whichever files/ folders are required offline, move them to a non-iCloud-synced place.
- Make their aliases and keep them in place of the original files/folders.
- If you need to sync those files somewhere else too, make another copy in iCloud.

If aliases don't work, check out symlinks.